# Java calling .exe without having to change path

Tags: java, windows, path, environment-variables, exe

I have the following situation. I have a Java-based software that uses a bundle of programs that are already compiled. So what this Java-based software does is to call/execute the .exe files of these libraries through the Runtime Java class using the exec() method in order to execute these auxiliary programs.

For this, I have a separated routine that modify the Windows PATH environment variable prior to the execution of my main software in order to be possible to access to the auxilary software through the mentioned Java class and its method.

However, I would like to call from Java these group of .exe without having to modify the Windows PATH. This is possible?

Solutions are heard. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe. But I would suggest you use an installer (like [NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System)) and deal with configuration there.

Comment: you can give the path directly if you use [Desktop.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))

Comment: @Madhan and thorugh the Desktop.open method can I pass parameters to .exe files?

Comment: For arguements you have to go with [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[]))

Comment: You can write a command (or batch) file that sets up the environment and use Runtime.exec()  to execute the command file.